# Interpretation of 95% confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval

I have a trouble understanding the concept/interpretation of confidence interval. It is commonly said that if I construct a hundred of 95-percent-confidence-intervals, then it is expected that 95 of those intervals would contain the true parameter. However, I am not sure why this should be true.

Question 1:

First, define a probability space and random variable: $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P) \underset{X}{\rightarrow} (\mathbb R, \Sigma)$, and all $X_i$'s are iid as $X$, where $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Fix sample size $n$ and let us create 100 samples, $\{X^1_1, \cdots, X^1_n\}, \cdots, \{X^{100}_1, \cdots, X^{100}_n\}$. For each sample, I may form sample mean and variance:
$\bar X^k = \frac{1}{n}\sum X^k_i$, and $(S^k)^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum (X^k_i - \bar X^k)^2$. For convenience reason, I shall say that $\mathbb P(X \in (\mu-2\sigma, \mu+2\sigma)) = 0.95$. I can construct 100 confidence intervals $I^1, \cdots, I^{100}$, where $I^k = (\bar X^k - 2S^k, \bar X^k + 2S^k)$. Clearly, taking expectation on $\bar X^k - 2S^k$ and $\bar X^k + 2S^k$ would yield:
$$\mathbb E[\bar X^k - 2S^k] = \mu - 2\sigma, \quad \quad \mathbb E[\bar X^k + 2S^k] = \mu + 2\sigma.$$

However, I have a difficulty of taking this idea to make a conclusion that "it is expected that 95 of 100 confidence intervals contain $\mu$." Or this idea could be completely irrelevant! Anyway, I would appreciate a clarification why "it is expected that 95 of 100 confidence intervals contain $\mu$."

2. If we drop the normality condition of $X$, then would construction of confidence interval still work? I feel that I am somehow abusing central limit theorem that the normalized variable would eventually converge (in distribution sense) to normal probability distribution.

Comment: Have a look at the various other questions on this site regarding the interpretation of confidence intervals. You will find that the 95 out of 100 version is not the only option. And to answer your number 2 question, there are different methods of constructing intervals for different types of data and sampling.

Comment: A couple of pointers: 1. you need to make the distinction between rv X and a sample x. The sample upper and lower confidence limits are constants so taking the expectation does nothing. 2.  The law of large numbers can be regarded as the source of the usual interpretation.

Comment: By *definition,* the event "my 95% confidence interval covers the true parameter" is a *binary* event with a 95% chance of occurring.  This observation reduces your question to "what is the expected number of outcomes in 100 flips of a coin that has a 95% chance of landing heads?"

Comment: $P[\bar X - 2S < \mu  < \bar X + 2S] = P[-2S < \bar X - \mu < 2S] = P[-2 < \frac{\bar X - \mu}{S} < 2]$. I am trying to link this to t-distribution, where $t = \frac{\bar X-\mu}{s/\sqrt{n}}$. How may I deal with $\sqrt n$ term here?

Comment: On a second thought, the correct statement would be: confidence interval would be constructed as $P[\bar X - 2S/\sqrt n < \mu  < \bar X + 2S/\sqrt n]$. Thanks.

Comment: The linked question in the closure statement has 12 answers (!), so you need to be discerning. I recommend the whuber answer.